# TLS 1.2 SQL Server and Delphi Client

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I would like to connect to SQL Server TLS 1.2 via delphi XE7 application. How would be make the connection string ? It is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the application connection string, you just need to add the following parameters; `Encrypt=True` and `TrustServerCertificate=False` and that's it!

Of course your server must be configured to use TLS 1.2. And the client library you use must be TLS enabled.

Comment: Why disable `TrustServerCertificate`?

Comment: This will force certificate chain validation.

Comment: what do you mean "And the client library you use must be TLS enabled " i  just make new connection string with SQLNCLI11.1 and Encrypt=True and TrustServerCertificate=False  and it works.  I use TAdoconnection

Comment: That means you have the correct client library (ADO connection is using a client library). So don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

I play with Provider=SQLNCLI11.1  and not SQLOLEDB.1 . I made Encrypt=True and TrustServerCertificate=False and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to microsoft Native SQL and SQLOLEDB is depricated and for a new development is OLEDB Driver :
[OLEDB Driver Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

I just replace provider with MSOLEDBSQL.1 and works